# How to block number that ends with specific digits?

Tags: calls, call-screening, auto-reject

I am receiving quite a few unwanted calls (6 yesterday), although I am blocking the numbers and [reporting all of them to Ofcom](http://consumers.ofcom.org.uk/phone/tackling-nuisance-calls-and-messages/recorded-message-marketing-calls/), I would rather simply not get them.

All of the phone numbers that are calling me end in "114", and this gave me an idea. Is there any way to block numbers that end with specific digits (or regex based)?